# Чтение строк из вызванной консоли

Tags: cmd, visual-studio, c++, mpi

После выполения mpi-проги в консоли появится строка `C:\Program Files\MPICH2\bin`. Каким образом можно ее прочитать? Если есть ссылки на данные команды, то поместите их в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_popen()`. Подробности смотри в [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).